# Remove shipping from Cart - Magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, cart, shipping, shipping-methods

Just as the title says I want to remove shipping cost from the cart total.  I don't even understand how it can assume that cost?

For my test customer I have 3 options:
[image]

The checkout page however comes after the cart?  So how can the cart even make an assumption that the customer is going to pick that one?

Here is the Cart Checkout:
[image]

I don't want the shipping settings ever saved or even for that matter displayed in the cart.  Because in the Checkout for Shipping Methods they will always have multiple options so I don't want the website remembering the last shipping method they chose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you previously went through and estimated your shipping for a previous cart, selected a shipping method, emptied that cart and came back later adding new itms to the cart.

Magento will "remember" certain details about a cart after all items are removed **and** the cart is not converted into an order.  It will keep your selected shipping method and destination zip code (as well as your billing and shipping addresses if you got that far) and potentially your method of payment, but not the credit card details.  This is done to expedite the conversion to a sale.

When you empty your cart you aren't deleting the cart; instead, you're just removing all items from the cart and leaving everything else in place including shipping methods selected, discount codes used, and address information.

My guess is that you are observing this functionality.

Comment: This is actually exactly what is happening thanks for posting!